# SASS Output Style automate with minified file

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, node-modules

I'm trying to do test to use correctly SASS and I want create a file style.css and that file minify to style.min.css

```html
sass --watch sass/style:css --style compressed
```

That works well but I need automate proccess doing compile & minify at the same time.

I've found this code in other stackoverflow:

```html
sass --watch sass/style.scss:css/style.css --watch css/style.css:css/style.min.css --style compressed --scss
```

but now dont work how I want that works.
Also at Sass webpage the code is different now on 2020.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass#style

I'm not use gulp tool because I think it not neccesary for Wordpress projects.

Anybody may help me?

Comment: Use `node-sass` is faster than `sass`
Usage is very simple `node-sass ./style.scss ./style.min.css -w --output-style compressed`

Comment: That not works. node-sass: The term 'node-sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file or executable program. Correctly if you typed correctly the
name or, if you included a path, verify that the path is correct and
Try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Irrespective of what you're building your site in, if you want total control over compilation/minification/whatever then well, that's what tooling such as gulp is there for.

It looks like you were trying to compile SCSS to CSS to a file, then take that compiled CSS file and minify it. That CLI tool won't do that, but it can absolutely do the compilation/compression at the same time, directly from the source SCSS.

Using the binary you're using, this is going to compile and compress, taking `./sass/style.scss` and outputting the result to `./css/style.min.css`

```
sass sass/style.scss:css/style.min.css --style compressed
```

Add  `--watch` if you want to have it react to file changes in your scss file.

Or perhaps you were trying to get a unminified and a minified version alongside. In that case, you'll simply have to run two commands. Again, gulp is there to automate this process.

Other binaries will have different flags and options, and of course there is the gulp option which I'd certainly recommend given you then don't have to remember any lengthy commands and you can share your chosen structure/tasks accross projects.

Comment: That works almost perfect. The only error is that output style.css and style.min.css has the same code minified. Is it working well?

Comment: This won't be making a style.css file, if that exists it has come from something you did previously